# Is there any way to find out why Preview Crashed on Xcode - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Sometimes my app crash, it shows - preview crashed.
So I have to find the reason manually.

So I'm looking for a solution If I can get the reason why my preview crashed, as we get the reason in android studio why the app stopped working(in the run log menu).

Comment: What do you mean by finding the reason manually? How would you go about you doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for crash logs from your application.